# Trying to edit model, keeps creating more (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, edit

I'm trying to edit my models, but it keeps just creating more models with the new given attributes.

I think I'm confused about methods and routes.

`/app/controllers/products_controller.rb`

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def index
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.create(params[:products])

    redirect_to @product
  end

  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end


  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @product.update_attributes(params[:id])
    @product.save
  end

  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy

    redirect_to "/products"
  end
end
```

`/app/views/products/edit.html.erb`

```
<br />
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title, "Title:" %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, size: 20 %>
    <br /><br />
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

## Edit

I updated my products controller and view, but now I'm getting a nil:NilClass error.

Comment: Looking at your Create action - do you know that `Model.create` saves automatically? So you don't need `Model.save` too

Comment: there is no `edit` action in controller and it should be a member path e.g. `/app/views/products/:id/edit.html.erb`

Comment: Yeah - edit action used to display the edit form - the data is then submitted to the update action

Comment: See my updated answer re: your `update` method

Comment: I'd also recommend making a sample rails project, and do something in the console like `rails generate scaffold Post name:string`. Then look at the `posts_controller.rb` file to see common idioms for creating/editing/updating records.

Comment: Scaffold! I KNEW I forgot something!

Answer (score 3):

Just use this instead:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
```

If `@product` is a new record, it will post to your `create` method, and if it's an existing record, it will post to your `update` method.

Your `update` method should be similar to this (you don't need to call `save`, `update_attributes` already saves it for you):

```
def update
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
end
```